# AWS CloudFront - When the "Regional Data Transfer Out to Origin" cost is charged?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

Sorry for my poor english.

I'm considering using AWS CloudFront and inquiring the pricing policy from https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/

Other sections are understandable for me, but I can't understand when the "Regional Data Transfer Out to Origin" cost is charged.

As I understood, a CDN only fetches data from origin server for caching and there is no need to transfer data out to origin server.

Which case a CDN sends data to origin server?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question which should be asked of the Customer Service department for the company you are dealing with. Please see: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Regional Data Transfer Out to Origin from Amazon CloudFront to Origin Server refers to using POST, PUT & etc. requests, where there is a request payload.

> Data Transfer out of Amazon CloudFront to your origin server (e.g. for
>   POST and PUT requests) will be billed at the “Regional Data Transfer
>   Out to Origin” rates listed in the Regional Data Transfer Out to
>   Origin (per GB) table.